# A guess for a mechanism behind Type Inference

Tags: swift, type-inference

I've tried this code in the xCode: `let bigNum = Int8.max + Int("1")!` The compiler infers the variable **bigNum** of type `Int8` and give me a overflow error.

For `Int8.max + Int("1")!`: the left side of **"+"** has the type of `Int8`  the right side has the type of `Int`. Why the compiler did not infer the **bigNum** as type of `Int` ?

**Guess**: Swift's compiler always infer the tye by the more narrow/restricted value types, because `Int8` is a more small and narrow type compare to the `Int`, therefore adding an `Int8` and an `Int` number would lead to an `Int8` type inference.

**Question**: Am I right? or mostly right but not precise. If so, please correct me.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type inference engine doesn't know the bit-width of the Ints. It doesn't even know that Ints are numbers. The engine doesn't know anything about the "restrictedness" or "narrowness" of how types are implemented. It just knows how types relate to each other as supertypes and subtypes ("ISA" relationships), and tries to solve constraint problems by figuring out what it can plug into the type variables you've provided.

The type inference engine instead is basing its choice on the version of `+` that is selected. None of the Int-based `+` functions apply. They're all of the form:

```
public func +(lhs: Int8, rhs: Int8) -> Int8
```

And this doesn't have an `Int8` on both sides. So it picks the next most specific one it can find:

```
public func +<T : Strideable>(lhs: T, rhs: T.Stride) -> T
```

Why this one? An `Int8` is a `SignedInteger`. `SignedInteger` implements `Strideable` this way:

```
public protocol Strideable : Comparable {
    associatedtype Stride : SignedNumber
    public func distance(to other: Self) -> Self.Stride
    public func advanced(by n: Self.Stride) -> Self
}

extension SignedInteger {
    public func distance(to other: Self) -> Int
    public func advanced(by n: Int) -> Self
}
```

By type-inference we see that `Stride` is `Int`. So our function is:

```
public func +(lhs: Int8, rhs: Int) -> Int8
```

And that of course overflows at runtime.

BTW, the best way to figure out what function Swift has chosen is to Option-Click the `+` symbol. It'll tell you what types it's using.

Comment: "BTW, the best way to figure out what function Swift has chosen is to Option-Click the + symbol. " Thanks a lot!